# How to check child in firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i need to avoid duplication of data in the table.
[image: here is the database]

when ever a new user add some information to the database if the "category" field data  is present then need to show this data is already present in the database.

```
   if(!group_link.isEmpty()&&!group_name.isEmpty()&&e2.length()<=50 && e2.length()>=40&&(e2.getText().toString().contains("https://chat.whatsapp.com/"))) {
                HashMap<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                datamap.put("category", selected_item);
                datamap.put("group_name", group_name);
                datamap.put("group_link", group_link);
                datamap.put("group_type",group_type);
                datamap.put("language",language);
                datamap.put("report_status",count);
                mref.push().setValue(datamap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(Usr_add.this, "Data Submited successfully :) ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e1.setText("");
                            e2.setText("");
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(Usr_add.this, "Something Wrong :( ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
```

i need to check if category data field is present or not.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Thomas have you try my answer?

Comment: not solved yet... its shows every time "stop it exist" toast when adding data every time.

Comment: yes if `category` exists it will show you that message...

Comment: no if the category not exist also it shows the same toast

Answer (score 0):

```
 DatabaseReference rf = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference retrieve = 
rf.child("type").child("Whatsapp").child("Shopping deals");
retrieve.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    for(DataSnapshot getdata : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        if (getdata.child("category").exists()) {
              Toast.makeText(this,"Stop it exists!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }}else{

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

First you query on `shopping deals`, since there is a random key there you have to a `for` loop to be able to reach the `name:value`. Then using the `exists()` you can see if any attribute exists in your firebase database. In this case we are checking if `category` exists by using `child("category")`

If it exists then add a `Toast` to the user or watever you want.. if it does not exist then maybe add it to the database using `setValue()`